# How to search a value in dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary some thing like this

```
{"instrumentation": {"pageLoadPingUrl": "https://www.bingapis.com/api/ping/pageload?IG=440721A6C23D4C6CB82AC171F1AFA42D&CID=28D84A8BE9D769B22E1C409BE8E66875&Type=Event.CPT&DATA=0"}, "_type": "Images", "displayRecipeSourcesBadges": true, "value": [{"contentUrl": "http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=440721A6C23D4C6CB82AC171F1AFA42D&CID=28D84A8BE9D769B22E1C409BE8E66875&rd=1&h=s-P4Ztx6KcC0GMLEtwRTL3gofaLcCzZiRHu13_GeP2w&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fwww.counter-currents.com%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2015%2f08%2ffootball.jpg&p=DevEx,5008.1", "accentColor": "7C2F2B", "height": 1131, "hostPageDisplayUrl": "www.counter-currents.com/2015/08/moving-the-movement-football", "name": "... Sallis, \"Moving the Movement Football\" | Counter-Currents Publishing", "width": 1698, "imageId": "DCE3B4704C97EC1064A12E7D693389AD809DA302", "imageInsightsToken": "ccid_8MPrFCUI*mid_DCE3B4704C97EC1064A12E7D693389AD809DA302*simid_608014267730954997", "datePublished": "2016-12-20T06:19:00", "encodingFormat": "jpeg", "webSearchUrl": "https://www.bing.com/cr?IG=440721A6C23D4C6CB82AC171F1AFA42D&CID=28D84A8BE9D769B22E1C409BE8E66875&rd=1&h=DxYxhRhR_W5Ww0BYlGqMNvRtnSpmF6AKMXkf6NmsymM&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fimages%2fsearch%3fview%3ddetailv2%26FORM%3dOIIRPO%26q%3dfootball%26id%3dDCE3B4704C97EC1064A12E7D693389AD809DA302%26simid%3d608014267730954997&p=DevEx,5006.1", "hostPageUrl": "http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=440721A6C23D4C6CB82AC171F1AFA42D&CID=28D84A8BE9D769B22E1C409BE8E66875&rd=1&h=Y8BcOh1scDstVMD9L56uNC37GdqPzFOWTieHej3va78&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fwww.counter-currents.com%2f2015%2f08%2fmoving-the-movement-football%2f&p=DevEx,5007.1", "thumbnailUrl": "https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Mf0c3eb142508ab40b0a7680f777f452fo0&pid=Api", "thumbnail": {"width": 300, "height": 199}, "contentSize": "2484792 B"}
```

I want to get the value of  **"thumbnailurl"**.

output should be

```
https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Mf0c3eb142508ab40b0a7680f777f452fo0&pid=Api
```

Comment: You don't have a valid dictionary there

Comment: i have parse json file into dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is a prefix but it is clear that the path to the value is:

```
D['value'][0]['thumbnailUrl']
```

The following is your JSON without the values that don't matter:

```
{
  "value": [{
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Mf0c3eb142508ab40b0a7680f777f452fo0&pid=Api",
  }]
}
```

The following shows that this is correct for the given example:

```
>>> D = {
...   "value": [{
...     "thumbnailUrl": "https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Mf0c3eb142508ab40b0a7680f777f452fo0&pid=Api",
...   }]
... }
>>> D['value'][0]['thumbnailUrl']
'https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Mf0c3eb142508ab40b0a7680f777f452fo0&pid=Api'
```

Comment: It is a text file

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a valid dictionary, a valid dictionary of your example should be like this

```
dict = {'thumbnailurl': 'https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Mf0c3eb142508ab40b0a7680f777f452fo0&pid=Api
', 'pageLoadPingUrl': 'https://www.bingapis.com/api/ping/pageload?IG=440721A6C23D4C6CB82AC171F1AFA42D&CID=28D84A8BE9D769B22E1C409BE8E66875&Type=Event.CPT&DATA=0'}
```

and you can get the value by **get** method

```
print "Value : %s" %  dict.get('thumbnailurl')
```

This method return a value for the given key. If key is not available, then returns default value None.

Comment: thumbnailurl is not a key its value of a  key which has also a value.